# Are prime gaps of even index essentially larger than those of odd index?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-constellations

Let $g_{n}:=p_{n+1}-p_{n}$ be the $n$- th prime gap, and let's introduce the following summatory functions:
$$G_{1}(x):=\sum_{1\leq n\leq x}g_{2n-1}$$
$$G_{2}(x):=\sum_{1\leq n\leq x}g_{2n}$$.

Let's now write $\mathcal{G}(x):=\sum_{k\leq x}\left(\dfrac{G_{2}(k)}{G_{1}(k)}-1\right)$.

Does this last series diverge? Converge towards a positive constant?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do we even know the property (weaker than the statement that the sum $\mathcal{G}(x)$ converges) that $\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{G_2(k)}{G_1(k)} = 1$?